# Cannot find correct args for rsync to pass to Java Runtime exec to ignore folders

Tags: java, unix, rsync, runtime.exec

I want to call rsync from Java using Runtime.exec() and I want to ignore hidden files/folders. The command is simple and works like a charm at the command line.

```
rsync -r --exclude=".*" source destination
```

I have tried many, many different combinations of breaking these arguments down correctly to be passed as a String[] to exec(). I have failed and I may be close to losing my mind.

Some examples of what I have tried

```
String[]{ "rsync", "-r", "--exclude", "=", ".*", source, destination});
String[]{ "rsync", "-r", "--exclude", "=", "\".*\"", source, destination});
String[]{ "rsync", "-r", "--exclude=\".*\"", source, destination});
```

Most of the time I end up with an [exit 23](http://wpkg.org/Rsync_exit_codes) (which is "partial transfer due to error"), the transfer completes but includes hidden files/folders.

Comment: Are you experiencing the problem on Windows or on Unix? The `exclude=".*"` part on Unix is generally handled by the shell and not the program itself. In such a case you could run `sh -c` before your command.

Comment: @Alex sorry, I should have specified - this is on a machine running Ubuntu.

Comment: Have you tried with "--exclude='.*'" or "--exclude=.\\*"? It might work around the shell globbing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said `".*"` is evaluated by the shell. Better place all options in a file and do `rsync @myfile`.

*BTW I wonder whether the original command excludes `.*` directories in subdirectories.*

Comment: interesting question - I'm trying to exclude .svn directories. Must check that out and make sure they are being excluded at all levels

Comment: And the answer is yes, it does exclude hidden items in subdirs.

Comment: Thanks for the backinfo; one gets paranoid.